# ROS2: how are msgs serialised (compared to ROS1)?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have two questions about the [Connection Header](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Connection%20Header):

1. I have a ROS1 application where I rely on  the [Connection Header](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Connection%20Header) and I would like to know how is that handle in ROS2? I am only concerned about messages.
2. Is it possible to "dump" the connection header (in ROS1 and/or ROS2) of a publisher for a given topic to a file?

Basically what I am trying to figure out if data is serialized the same way in ROS2 as it was in ROS1 to be transmitted. That means, starting 4 bytes with total length of the entire message and then each variable with its bytes and its length if it is a string or array.

Thanks for the help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/371410/ros2:-how-are-msgs-serialised-(compared-to-ros1)?/) by [Ariel](https://answers.ros.org/users/23277/ariel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 65 on 2021-02-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Basically what I am trying to figure out if data is serialized the same way in ROS2 as it was in ROS1 to be transmitted.

No, not at all.

ROS 2 uses DDS by default (there are other middleware choices).

See [the ROS 2 design site](https://design.ros2.org). The articles about the middleware choice(s) are probably interesting and relevant.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-02-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ariel](https://answers.ros.org/users/23277/ariel/) on 2021-02-10**:
So that is for the communication part, but for what I understood, `ROS2`uses [FAST-CDR](https://github.com/eProsima/Fast-CDR) for the serialization, before broadcasting it. So my 2nd question was if it is possible to get that serialization as well for a given message in the node itself?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-02-10**:
As you should know, posting follow-up questions as comments under questions which have been answered is not a good idea. Those questions (and any potential answers) have very low visibility.

Asking two questions in a single post here on ROS Answers isn't a good idea in general.

You might want to post a new question.

**Comment by [Ariel](https://answers.ros.org/users/23277/ariel/) on 2021-02-10**:
Good point. Just in case, I found the answer by using this: http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/MessagesSerializationAndAdaptingTypes